How can I get the memory distance in bytes between any two objects (if this measurement exists in a meaningful way)?
Pointer arithmetic is only defined behavior for pointers to elements of the same array (or one past the array).
Is there any defined behavior to get the distance in memory between two elements that are not in the same array?
For example, say I have a function that jumps around in memory to access values to calculate something (values not in the same array or object). I want to know how big the jumps are (and print them out, in bytes) to determine if cache misses might occur and their severity. Is this possible?
If my understanding is correct that a pointer contains an absolute virtual address (absolute for a given process), then within a process it seems to make intuitive sense that this should be possible.

There's no portable way, guaranteed by the standard. But for testing/analysis purposes there might be a way (subtracting addresses) that would work for a specific compiler version and system. Having said that - there are probably better tools (system dependant) to analyze cache misses and other profiling aspects .

the memory distance in bytes between any two objects, if these two objects are not in an object or an array, is undefined behavior,

If cache misses might be an issue, you should tackle this by design of your datastructures (algorithms and threading behavior). Not by trying to guess how data may be placed in memory after the fact. (e.g. have a look at entity component systems)

Modern cache hardware is smart enough that it can easily handle two or possibly even three distinct patches of ram access provided that you do it in the right way. Separation distance is meaningless now on most memory systems. Cache aware code invariably works on tiles with a size chosen to fit in cache. Most important is that all writes to memory should be sequential if at all possible. Purging dirty cache line for a single update is expensive.

Let's say I have object Alpha at location $D000 bank 1, and object Beta at different location $D000 bank 7, in a banked memory architecture machine.  You may get something useful with a "fat pointer" (bank + address), but not a regular pointer.  Likewise, with a segmented memory architecture machine, unless you do some normalization on the big pointer or huge pointer.

The difference may not make sense.  Let's say that objectA is at 0x3000 in DRAM while objectB is at 0x8000 in Flash memory.  This is a case where the objects are in different types of memory, so the distance doesn't have meaning.

Another example:  obj1 is the address of the read status register of a USART.  obj2 is the address of the DMA controller status register.  Both objects have addresses outside of an array.  Their distance does not have any real meaning.


Is there any defined behavior to get the distance in memory between two elements that are not in the same array?

No, generally this doesn't exist because memory doesn't even need to have a flat layout in which this would make sense.
However, in most implementations you can do
auto addr1 = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&obj1);
auto addr2 = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&obj2);
auto distance = addr1 >= addr2 ? addr1-addr2 : addr2-addr1;

The behavior and mapping used by the cast is however implementation-defined and doesn't have to relate to addresses on the system.

For example, say I have a function that jumps around in memory to access values to calculate something (values not in the same array or object).

Note that even if the above is possible on the implementation, then you are generally still not allowed to simply use the numeric values obtained above to reconstruct a pointer to some object somewhere in memory with reinterpret_cast and access that.
The whole point for the restrictions on pointer arithmetic is that the compiler is permitted to assume that it is impossible to reach from one memory allocation or variable to another memory allocation or variable. That is necessary to make various kinds of analysis possible for optimization.
But for checking alignment and such this is a valid approach.
